# Long running async method vs firing an event upon completion

Tags: events, async-await, task, c#-7.0, event-driven

I have to create a library that communicates with a device via a COM port.

In the one of the functions, I need to issue a command, then wait for several seconds as it performs a test (it varies from 10 to 1000 seconds) and return the result of the test:

One approach is to use async-await pattern:

```
public async Task<decimal> TaskMeasurementAsync(CancellationToken ctx = default)
{
    PerformTheTest();

    // Wait till the test is finished
    await Task.Delay(_duration, ctx);

    return ReadTheResult();
 }
```

The other that comes to mind is to just fire an event upon completion.

The device performs a test and the duration is specified prior to performing it.  So in either case I would either have to use `Task.Delay()` or `Thread.Sleep()` in order to wait for the completion of the task on the device.

I lean towards `async-await` as it easy to build in the cancellation and for the lack of a better term, it is self contained, i.e. I don't have to declare an event, create a `EventArgs` class etc.

Would appreciate any feedback on which approach is better if someone has come across a similar dilemma.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools available for how to structure your code.

**Events** are a *push* model (so is System.Reactive, a.k.a. "LINQ over events"). The idea is that you subscribe to the event, and then your handler is invoked zero or more times.

**Tasks** are a *pull* model. The idea is that you start some operation, and the `Task` will let you know when it completes. One drawback to tasks is that they only represent a single result.

The coming-soon **async streams** are also a *pull* model - one that works for multiple results.

In your case, you are starting an operation (the test), waiting for it to complete, and then reading the result. This sounds very much like a *pull* model would be appropriate here, so I recommend `Task<T>` over events/Rx.